# Fullcalendar I want businnes hours to appear in only one day

Tags: fullcalendar

```
var ExtraDiaSemana = [5];



            var horarioExtra = { start: value.HoraInicio, end: value.HoraFim, dow: ExtraDiaSemana, dowstart: new Date(value.DataInicio), dowend: new Date(value.DataFim)};
            horariosAtendimento.push(horarioExtra);
```

businessHours: horariosAtendimento

Comment: Please read about asking [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you get the idea for "dowstart" and "dowend" from? I don't see them mentioned in the documentation as valid properties. Perhaps you need to add some custom code to actually make use of them.

Comment: Yes, dowstart does not work, what properties do I need to put to appear only on a specific day?